# Reuse same UIView on multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

**Background -** I have an app with three `UIVIewControllers` that act like sub-apps i.e. they show very different content from each other (but are similarly themed).  For example you could have an 'animals app' and the three `UIViewControllers` could be 'dog', 'cat', 'rabbit'.  These have a `UINavigationBar` with a 'settings' button that loads a custom `UIView`. This `UIView` animates onto the screen and shows settings specific to that `UIViewController`.

**Problem -** I would like to have one `UIView` that can get called by any of the `UIViewControllers` but it's contents, in this case a submenu, would be specific to that 'sub app'.

**My progress so far -** I have managed to get the `UIView` working fine if the code is all written in the same `UIViewController` which calls it.  What is the correct way of creating the `UIView`, calling it with parameters (such as what to put in the submenu).

At the moment I have the following code on the NavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem:

```
-(void)showSettings:(id)sender
{
    if (_menuCounter == 0) {
        [self addOverlay];
        _settingsSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((_screenWidth * 0.5), (_barHeight - (_screenHeight * 0.5)), (_screenWidth * 0.5), (_screenHeight * 0.5))];
        _settingsSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        NSLog(@"Settings width  = %fl", _barHeight);
        NSLog(@"Screen width    = %fl", _screenWidth);
        NSLog(@"Settings X      = %fl, Settings height = %fl", _settingsSubView.frame.origin.x, _settingsSubView.frame.size.height);

        UITableView *settingsTSV = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((_screenWidth * 0.05), (_barHeight), (_screenWidth * 0.4), (_screenHeight * 0.4))];

        UIButton *settingsCloseBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [settingsCloseBtn setFrame:CGRectMake((_screenWidth * 0.4), (_screenHeight * 0.45), (_screenWidth * 0.1), (_screenHeight * 0.05))];

        [settingsCloseBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [settingsCloseBtn setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [settingsCloseBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(closeMenu)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [settingsCloseBtn setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];

        [_settingsSubView addSubview:settingsTSV];
        [_settingsSubView addSubview:settingsCloseBtn];

        [self.view addSubview:_settingsSubView];
        [self openMenu];
    } else {
        [self closeMenu];
    }
}
-(void)closeMenu
{
    _menuCounter = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    [_settingsSubView setFrame:CGRectMake((_screenWidth * 0.5), (_barHeight - (_screenHeight * 0.9)), (_screenWidth * 0.5), (_screenHeight * 0.5))];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"%fl",_settingsSubView.frame.origin.y);
    [_overlayView removeFromSuperview];
}
-(void)openMenu
{
    _menuCounter = 1;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    [_settingsSubView setFrame:CGRectMake((_screenWidth * 0.5), (_barHeight), (_screenWidth * 0.5), (_screenHeight * 0.5))];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)addOverlay
{
    _overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, _barHeight, _screenWidth, _screenHeight)];
    _overlayView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
    [self.view addSubview:_overlayView];
}
```

So, how would I make it so that a `UIView` (SubMenuView) can be called by any of the `UIViewControllers` and have the same animation that I have here but with different parameters loaded based on the 'requesting' `UIVewController`?

**Edit -** I have tried a few more things and can't seem to get this working, not sure categories are what I need right now as I seem to be stuck on a 'stage before the use of categories' as in; I can't even load the `UIView` properly yet.  Here is a image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Note that the three `UIViewControllers` are different but the `UIView` that includes a sub menu is the same `UIView` but before it is loaded, different parameters are sent so when it draws it has the correct menu items.

In have also tried to import the SubMenuView.h and then create an instance of it:

```
SubMenyView *subMenuViewInstance = [SubMenuView alloc] innit];
[self.view addSubView:subMenuViewInstance];
```

SubMenuView.m is then loaded but it has no reference to the `UIViewController` that called it so I can't draw the `UIView` or edit the `UINavigationController`.  Doing this from the `UIViewController` I would normally just use

```
[self.view addSubView:_settingsSubView];
// Run the method that animates the UIView onto the screen...
```

So basically, how do I do those last two lines with a separate `UIView` class rather than writing all the code within the UIViewController.m of each of the `UIViewControllers`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Category for example:

```
#import "UIView+OpticalEffects.h"

@implementation UIView (OpticalEffects)

- (void)configureShadowWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    //and so on
}

- (void)configureShadowWithBlackColor 
{
    [self configureShadowWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}


- (UIImageView *)imageViewFromView 
{
    CGRect screenRect = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
//and so on
    return capturedImageView;
}

- (void)addInnerVerticalShadow 
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer] ;
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, self.bounds.size.height);
//and so on
}

@end
```

Comment: How would I call this from one of the UIViewControllers?

Comment: You can use the category now anytime you create a UIView. Only need to import the .h file. The methods are then accessible. (Dont forget to make them public in the .h file.

Comment: here is a link to a tutorial: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll take a read now and try to implement something based on this to test.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I don't think this is what I need just yet.  See my edit.